# How to set multiple segue ViewController in TableViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue

While I only have one Cell in my TableViewController like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfvKK.png)

I set multiple cells with code and segue to different ViewController when be clicked.

How to connect my TableViewController with multiple ViewController for I'm going to set ViewController's segue identifier.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to check the value of the table cell for choosing which view controller that you need.

Comment: @JackyShek Thanks, I mean I need to set my each table view cell connect to different view controller, then I could set segue identifier. but I only have one cell in my table view controller in storyboard...

Comment: You need to do it in programming, rather than just using storyboard. These 2 tutorials may help you: 

https://www.ralfebert.de/tutorials/ios-swift-uitableviewcontroller/

http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-uitableviewcell-taps-swift/

Comment: @JackyShek Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Make a segue from the controller not from the cell
2. call a  didselectrow atindexpath method of tableview
3. call a prepare for segue with the identifier you have set for different segues
4. you are done

Comment: Thanks a loooooooot! try to connect from TableViewController to other view controller, not from Cell!